# When putting an image on the web that has only a few colours, what are the drawbacks of using the .bmp format?

Tags: bitmap

Say I have an image that is 500px square, and uses only about 10 colours, including some large single-colour blocks. Both .jpg and .png are lossy and cause fuzz, and .svg can be quite awkward to work with using my offline editor, Inkscape. The 16-colour .bmp format gives the image a file size of 125kB, which is acceptable even though it's more than 10 times what I'd get using .svg. But .bmp is rarely used in such circumstances. What are its drawbacks here?

Comment: Have you tried .gif or .png? .bmp is hopelessly outdated.

Comment: jpg compression can be adjusted, and PNG-24 is usually without artifacts. BMP is quite big, so thats a drawback.

Comment: I'm finding .png lossy and the editor I use can't save as png-24. The size of the .bmp files isn't a problem in what I'm doing. I love .bmp because you can control every pixel (and it's clear what the bytes are for), although I don't need such precision. But .gif, yes! I think .gif is the answer. With 16 colours it's giving me as good a result as .bmp but at 7% of the size. While the size saving isn't crucial, everything other than size seems in practice to be equal, so .gif it is.